# JUnit Error Response code 500

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded a script in Badboy software.
The steps I have followed:

1. Login into the site; it redirects to the info page and logs out.
2. Upload jmx file into JMeter, add view result tree and summary report, and run the script.

But it displays an error on the info page. How can I resolve this error?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that you can replay Login event as modern web applications widely use dynamic parameters i.e. for page level state management (see [Viewstate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx) for example) or security tokens to verify user origin (see i.e. [CSRF Token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery))

I would recommend recording your scenario 2 times and see if there are any differences. If they are - you will need to work them around using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), the process is known as **[correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations)**

Also remember that Response Assertion in your case applies to all requests, if you need to apply it to i.e. `Info` request only you need to add it **as a child** of that request, see [JMeter Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) for more details.

In general HTTP Status Code 500 stands for [Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500), going forward I would suggest checking your application logs to see what went wrong.